# Dokka is not generating documentation for test package

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, documentation-generation, kotlin-dokka

I have KDoc style comments in my tests code and I want to generate documentation using Kotlin DSL Gradle dokkaHtml tasks. But after successfully executing the task it says **"Exiting Generation: Nothing to document"**.

I have tried to set sources but nothing has changed. I want to get the html documentation for code in my test package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dokka is meant to be used to document source code of libraries, to provide documentation to publish about how your API works. The `test` source set is supposed to contain unit tests for testing the library code, and not neccesarily to also document the library; that's the job of the library itself, the `main` source set. Sample functions (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html#sample-identifier) would generate documentation, though. Alternatively, you can configure dokka to consider the `test` source set as source code, and not testing code:

```
tasks.withType<DokkaTask>().configureEach {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        named("test") {
            sourceRoots.from(file("src/test/"))
        }
    }
}
```

See also: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/dokka-gradle.html#source-set-configuration

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Comment: No. I wrote this myself.